# Using observables in Angular 2 / Ionic app

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am having trouble with my observables.  I am attempting to display comments using the `async` pipe:

```
<p *ngFor="let comment of client_comments$ | async">
  {{ comment }}
</p>
```

and I initialize `comments$` as follows:

```
// Ionic lifecycle hook for view loading
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.client_comments$ = this.commentService.getClientComments()
}
```

and the service looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class CommentsProvider implements OnInit {

  private client_comments  = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  client_comments$: Observable<any[]>

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {
    this.client$ = this.clientService.clientStream$
    this.client$.subscribe( client => {
      this.client = client
    })
  }

  initializeClientComments() {
    let client_comments = _.orderBy(this.client.comments, 'created_at', 'desc')
    this.client_comments$ = this.client_comments.asObservable()
    this.client_comments.next(client_comments)
  }

  addComment(comment) {
    let clientCommentArray = _.cloneDeep(this.client_comments.getValue())
    clientCommentArray.unshift(comment)
    this.client_comments.next(clientCommentArray)
  }

  getClientComments() : Observable<any[]> {
    this.initializeClientComments()
    return this.client_comments$
  }
}
```

When I add a comment, the value does not persist, I believe due to the call to `initializeClientComments()` because when I change `getClientComments()` to:

```
getClientComments() : Observable<any[]> {
  if (_.isEmpty(this.client_comments.getValue())) {this.initializeClientComments()}
  return this.client_comments$
}
```

the comment array is updated as expected.  But when I use the updated `getClientComments()`, and change from one client to another client, the view will show the first client's comments and will not change with the client.  I am thinking the constructor is not firing, causing no update in the client.

Client Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientService implements OnInit {

  private client = new BehaviorSubject("");
  clientStream$ = this.client.asObservable();

    constructor (private http: Http, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public storage: Storage, private app: App, private emailComposer: EmailComposer, private platform: Platform, private globalVarService: GlobalVariablesProvider) {}

  setClient(new_client) {
    this.client.next(new_client)
  }
}
```

How should I refactor this to allow the comment stream to remain in sync?

Comment: what is this.client in the service?

Comment: I added what I thought was relevant